# How can you retain the quotation marks when outputting a shell variable?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, formatting, string-formatting

The following line:

```
`eval echo echo $VAR=\\$$VAR` >> $FILE
```

will output to a file called `$FILE`:

```
FOO=value_of_full
BAR=value_of_bar
```

I want to I output quotes, such as in:

```
FOO="value_of_full"
BAR="value_of_bar"
```

I have already tried using `\"` and `""` but both did not work as I expected.

Comment: Do you expect the values to contain quotes? Do you really need them quoted all the time or only when necessary?

Comment: @Michał Górny: in fact only when necessary. This is going to be a list of values to be exported, and some of them have white spaces. For them, I need the quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is your `eval` that is swallowing up your quotes.

You can use [indirect variable referencing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver2.html#EX78) with bash >= 2.0 to alleviate the need for the `eval`:

```
echo "${VAR}=\"${!VAR}\"" >> $FILE
```

Unfortunately, double (or triple...) dereferences arn't supported, so you can't do `${!!VAR}` or `${!${!VAR}}` -- you still have to resort to the `eval` method for those. But I don't think you need that in this case.

If you really do want to use `eval`, then you will have to double-escape your escapes, like this:

```
eval echo "$VAR=\\\"\$$VAR\\\"" >> $FILE
```

Or, if you really need the extra level of execution (as in your example above), then you need to triple-escape your escapes!

```
`eval echo echo $VAR=\\\\\"\\$$VAR\\\\\"` >> $FILE
```

Personally, I prefer the 1st method :-)

Comment: The first method would be the best one, but it didn't work for me. It gave me a "susbtitution error" if I'm not mistaken. The third one worked perfectly. I really must understand the tripe-escape case. :)

Comment: @Paulo: are you using bash? or some other shell, like csh or zsh?

Comment: I'm using ksh. At least this is what the first line of the script says: `#! /usr/bin/ksh`. I definitely am not an expert in shell script, and this is an old script created by someone else. I'm still trying to understand how some things work in this world.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but I don't get how you are using `VAR` for both the name and value of the variable.

```
#!/bin/sh
FILE=/tmp/out.txt
VAR1_NAME=foo
VAR1_VALUE=foo_value

echo "$VAR1_NAME=\"$VAR1_VALUE\"" >> $FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is the number of escapes you need to keep the quotes across that single line... it's easier if you separate it out using an intermediary variable:

```
#!/bin/sh
FILE=out.txt
VAR=BAR
BAR="value of bar"
eval TMP="\$$VAR"
echo $VAR=\"$TMP\" >> $FILE
```

`out.txt` will now contain:

```
BAR="value of bar"
```

Notice you need quotes on line 4 if BAR has spaces, line 5 again if BAR might have spaces.  On line 6 to get quotes around the value you need the `\"` wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

Quick check on KSH - following works.

Is it something else that you are attempting? What shell are you in?

```
FILE=myfile
VAR1="some text"
echo "VAR1=\"${VAR1}\"" > $FILE
```

**cat myfile**

```
VAR1="some text"
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash, you could do:

```
declare -p FOO BAR
```

Sadly, I can't recall a simple, portable way of getting that in POSIX sh.

Answer (score 0):

#### Best two methods (likely bash only);

1. **`printf`** `"%q=%q" VAR 'some value with special characters'`
2. ***Magic Aliases*** (invented by Simon Tatham[1](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/aliases.html#RelatedHacks)):

.

```
echo-literally-helper() {
    str="`history 1 | perl -pe 's/^ *[0-9]+ +[^ ]+ //'`"
    echo "$str"
}
alias echo-literally='echo-literally-helper #'
```

<sub>[Description and explanation here](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/aliases.html#RelatedHacks)</sub>

You can use this *monstrosity* like this:

```
echo-literally some *highly* risky 'set' of $IMPOSSIBLE unquoted; literals&
```

Which will duly output nothing but the literal text without *ANY* expansion or modification done. The trick is that it

- transforms the alias params into a trailing comment
- it canibalizes the bash history to get the comment out unmodified as a string value

You got to admire this cunning hack. I'm sure you'll be wise enough not to apply it in serious environments :)

[1](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/aliases.html#RelatedHacks) [Magic Aliases: A Layering Loophole in the Bourne Shell](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/aliases.html)